# wpf how to find a canvas inside a grid in a specific Row/column

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a grid divided into several rows/columns, how can i get the canvas that's inside that grid in (x,y) for example how can i get the canvas which is inside the row 2 column 1 ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple elements in a "cell", there probably is no nice way to do this, i would use a query like this:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
var target = (from UIElement c in grid.Children
         where Grid.GetRow(c) == y && Grid.GetColumn(c) == x
         select c).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

building on H.B's solution, i'd add a small test on the "Canvas" part of the question:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
var target = (from UIElement c in grid.Children
         where Grid.GetRow(c) == y && Grid.GetColumn(c) == x && c is Canvas
         select c).First();
```